# Make Visio layer visible through Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I am trying to make a layer in Visio visible through an Excel Macro, that I wrote. However, I always an invalid parameter error.

This is my code:

```
Sub visio_change_shape(index_value As Variant)

Dim AppVisio As Object
Dim VisioSystems As Object

Set AppVisio = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")

AppVisio.Pages(1).Layers.Item(index_value).CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = "1"

End Sub
```

However, in visio the same line works:

```
Private Sub Select_layers()
Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
Dim vsoLayers As Visio.Layers
Dim vsoLayer As Visio.Layer

Set vsoPage = ActivePage
Set vsoLayers = vsoPage.Layers

vsoLayer.CellsC(visLayerVisible).FormulaU = "1"

Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: Is `visLayerVisible` a Visio constant that Excel won't have any idea about?  The same as Visio won't understand what `xlUp` is all about.

Comment: Trying using `4` instead of `visLayerVisible` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.layer.cellsc

Comment: Add a reference to Visio in Excel

Comment: thanks for the pointers guys! `4` didn't fix it, but I know now where the problem is :)

Comment: why doesn't AppVisio.Pages(1).Layers.Item(index_value).CellsC(AppVisio.visCellIndices.visLayerVisible).FormulaU = "1" work?

Comment: After your AppVisio there should be a reference to the document, not the pages, so you should have something like: AppVisio.ActiveDocument.Pages(1) ... or even better AppVisio.ActiveDocument.ActivePage ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @PaulHerber. When I use AppVisio.ActiveDocument.ActivePage.Layers.Item(18).CellsC(AppVisio.visCellIndices.visLayerVisible).FormulaU = 1 I still get the error that the object does not support the property or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you actually need is:

ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Layers.Item(index_value).CellsC(visLayerVisible).Formula = "1"

index_value should be a short int.

Comment: Much easier than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest you download and instal the Visio SDK. There are many examples of code in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just installed it :)